# No such module when run tests in terminal

Tags: ios, swift, terminal, xctest

I get "No such module 'cms_ios'" during building when I am running tests in Terminal but It works fine I run them through XCode. Here is the command:

> xcodebuild test -workspace cms-ios.xcworkspace -scheme cms-tests
> -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=15.5' -only-testing cms-tests/Tests/Product/ChoicesProductTests

I checked Product Module Name in Build Settings and it is the same. What could be the reason?

Comment: Did this work previously? Do you have the command line tools?

Comment: Yes, I have command line tools

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared when I added a test plan